# Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.SQLState: S0001ErrorCode: 156 when working with Squirrel client

Tags: mysql, squirrel-sql

Iam trying to write a PL/SQL function in Squirrel client. when Iam tryin to excute a script in squirrel getting this error. Please help me as Im new to this squirrel client.

**Script:**

```
CREATE  FUNCTION totalHoliday
RETURN int IS
   total int:= 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into total
   FROM dbo.HOLIDAY;
   RETURN total;
END;
/
```

**Error:** Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 156
Error occured in:
CREATE  FUNCTION totalHoliday
RETURN int IS
   total int:= 0

I tried by giving AS Instead of IS but did'nt work..

Comment: Btw: MySQL does not support PL/SQL, that's an Oracle specific language.

Comment: can you provide me the correct syntax to work it on squirrel..

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-views.html

Comment: Thanks for your links. I gone through the link provided by you and picked up the sample code which was defined it, but still im facing the problem. Snippet of the code taken from the below link which of MYSQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html 
CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20))
 RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
     RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');  Error Msg showing in squirrel is: Error: Incorrect syntax near 's'.
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 102

Comment: Much appreciated if you provide me the simple MYSQL function example which runs on squirrel client. Version of squirrel which im using is Squirrel SQL Client Version 3.5.3 connected with MicrosoftMSSQL Server JDBC Driver

Comment: You can't connect to **MySQL** using the ***Microsoft* SQL Server** driver. Where does SQL Server suddenly come from? Which DBMS are you ***really*** using? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? Something totally different?

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL tab in the Session Properties dialog change the Statement Separator from `;` to `/`.